# Getting the next item in a loop

Tags: python, google-app-engine, loops, django-templates

What I want to do is quite simple: I have a model which I am running a regroup loop on. Now I want to show the first 4 items of the loop next to each other, and then continue on the next line with the next 4 items until the list is done. If there are no more items, the other cells on the line can stay empty.

I have tried to understand how I can use iterations here, but haven't been able to figure out how it fits to what I have. Also, I have the idea that it should be possible to do this in a simpler way... Below I copied the code that I have now, which obviously shows the first item of the loop 4 times, then 4 times the second one, etc.

I know there are some similar questions on this website, but I haven't been able to leverage them to develop a solution for my question. I'm running Python on Google App Engine. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
{% regroup communities|dictsort:"in_country" by in_country as community_list %}

{% for in_country in community_list %}
<h2 style="font-size:16px;">{{ in_country.grouper }}</h2>

<table cellspacing="0">
{% for item in in_country.list|dictsort:"name" %}

<tr style="text-align:center;">
 <td width="200px" class='community_table'>
    <img src="{{ item.image }}" style="height:40px;"><br />
    <a href='{{ item.url }}' style="font-size:10px; margin-left:10px;" TARGET = "_blank">{{ item.name }}</a><br />
    {{ item.com_type }}<br />
    {{ item.in_city }}<br />
 </td>

 <td width="200px" class='community_table'>
    <img src="{{ item.image }}" style="height:40px;"><br />
    <a href='{{ item.url }}' style="font-size:10px; margin-left:10px;" TARGET = "_blank">{{ item.name }}</a><br />
    {{ item.com_type }}<br />
    {{ item.in_city }}<br />
 </td>

 <td width="200px" class='community_table'>
    <img src="{{ item.image }}" style="height:40px;"><br />
    <a href='{{ item.url }}' style="font-size:10px; margin-left:10px;" TARGET = "_blank">{{ item.name }}</a><br />
    {{ item.com_type }}<br />
    {{ item.in_city }}<br />
 </td>

 <td width="200px" class='community_table'>
    <img src="{{ item.image }}" style="height:40px;"><br />
    <a href='{{ item.url }}' style="font-size:10px; margin-left:10px;" TARGET = "_blank">{{ item.name }}</a><br />
    {{ item.com_type }}<br />
    {{ item.in_city }}<br />
 </td>

{% endfor %}     
</table>  

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This question has nothing whatsoever to do with Python.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Disagree. The app is written in Python, it's using a Python templating engine, and the solution may plausibly be "do your grouping in Python before passing to the template".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<table cellspacing="0">
{% for item in in_country.list|dictsort:"name" %}

{% if forloop.counter0|divisibleby:4 %}
<tr style="text-align:center;">
{% endif %}

 <td width="200px" class='community_table'>
    <img src="{{ item.image }}" style="height:40px;"><br />
    <a href='{{ item.url }}' style="font-size:10px; margin-left:10px;" TARGET = "_blank">{{ item.name }}</a><br />
    {{ item.com_type }}<br />
    {{ item.in_city }}<br />
 </td>

{% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:4 %}
 </tr>
{% endif %}

{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I see what you are trying to do and it is actually a lot more logical than my attempt. However when trying the code it gives an error: 

TemplateSyntaxError: Invalid filter: 'divisible_by'

By the way, shouldn't the 'forloop.counter' at the end also end with a 0 (forloop.counter0)

Comment: Sorry, should be [`divisibleby`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/signals/#connecting-to-signals-sent-by-specific-senders). And no, you want the first tag to appear only on rows 0, 4, 8 etc, but the last one to appear on rows 3, 7, 11 etc.

Comment: I figured it out :) it was divisibleby instead divisible_by. For the rest I left it as it was. Thank you very much!

PS. Read your comment after writing the above

Comment: It's interesting to see the question and answer since my use case is similar: Displaying items in a list with types from cities. I also use a table for the layout and GAE + Jinja2 for rendering and django's i18n library of .po and .mo files for localization. Thank you for sharing how you do it

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest grouping your rows in your Python code before passing it to the template. You can do this using iterators like this:

```
my_iter = iter(my_list)
grouped = zip(my_iter, my_iter, my_iter, my_iter) # or zip(*[my_iter]*4)
```

Comment: Thanks Nick. I looked into the iter function before posting the question but I didn't understand the thing. Guess I'll be going back to the documentation on that one :) Thanks again!